# I can't rollback migrations, because the migration file does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, rollback

I added a migration in branch "add_dogs" with migration `db/migrate/20221220155010_create_dogs.rb`, and ran `db:migrate`.

Later on, I changed branches (without a merge), and ultimately abandoned the "new_dogs" branch.

Later later on, I checked out "add_cats" branch with `db/migrate/20221101010101_create_cats.rb`, and ran `db:migrate`. So far, all is well.

But then I tweak the "add_cats" migration (before committing anything), and ran `db:rollback` so I can run it again. I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownMigrationVersionError:

No migration with version number 20221220155010.
```

I can still run `db:migrate` on new migrations just fine, but not `db:rollback` or `db:migrate:redo`.

This makes sense, because the database has a record of applying `20221220155010`, but that migration file no longer exists, so there is no way to roll it back.

How can I get past this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are three ways to deal with a missing migration file, depending on your needs and access:

1. For a quick temporary fix, you can roll back just the migration you're currently editing so you can run it again. This may be useful if the other migration is still in the pipeline on the other branch and both eventually will get merged.

```
    rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20230101010101  
    // This is the version of the migration you WANT to rollback, not the missing one.
```

2. If the missing migration will never come back, you want a permanent fix. The simplest way is to remove that record from the database. You can do this from your favorite SQL client, rails console, etc. (I suppose you could even write a migration to do that, but that seems *mighty* sketchy.)

```
    DELETE FROM schema_migrations WHERE version = '20221220155010'
    -- This is the version of the migration that is MISSING, not the one you are working on.
```

3. If you don't have direct access to the database for whatever reason, you can give Rails a placebo to rollback. Ensure the timestamp in the filename matches the missing migration's version number.

Create a file named `db/migrations/20221220155010_just_kidding.rb`:

```
    class JustKidding < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        # nothing to see here.
      end
    end
```

Then, `rails db:rollback` will roll back that no-op migration and delete `20221220155010` from the schema_migrations table. You can now delete the placebo migration forever and you'll be in good shape as far as running migrations and rollbacks.

However...don't forget that the *effects* of the old migration are still in your schema. Maybe you're stuck with a new, unused 'dogs' table or an extra column on a table. Maybe that's benign on your dev box, but you certainly don't want that cruft on a production environment. All the advice in this answer assumes you're on a throw-away environment and that the effects of the old migration aren't a problem. Tearing down your whole database and rebuilding may become a more attractive option in this case.

One of the realy take-aways here is... *don't let this happen in the first place!* Ideally, you should rollback any new, uncommitted migrations before changing away from a branch. But...things happen...

p.s. If there is a way to do this from the command line, I'd love to learn it. I'm imagining something like `rails db:migrate:delete VERSION=20230101010101` might be handy in a hackish kind of way.

Comment: If you're using revision control, then you could grab `20221220155010_create_dogs.rb` out of your history, bring it to the new branch, and roll it back to get a clean database and `schema.rb`. I tend to keep separate database dumps for each branch and then dump/restore when switching branches.

Comment: Arguably you should never have to actually roll back a deleted migration. Migrations are just simple transformations of the database schema and should be deleted as soon as they are migrated onto all environments. Your schema.rb or structure.sql is the actual source of truth. If performing a migration leads to some sort of regression for example in production you don't solve the issue with a rollback (unless its detected immediately). Instead you write a new migration to undo the damage / mitigate the new bug.

Comment: Rollbacks are really just used in the case where you discover (early) that the migration doesn't have the intended effects. If you're working like in this case and switching branches and end up with a database schema in dev/test thats out of whack you solve it by rebuilding the database from schema.rb/structure.sql - not by running all the migrations.